# HTTP Error 500 Internal server error on high load ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, http-error

I get `HTTP Error 500 Internal server error` on a one simple page asp.net application. There are enough resources on the server. This page is frequently requested by a large number of clients.

Is there any `IIS` related settings I have missed ?

Comment: Does it crash consistently i.e. just doesn't work at all or is it intermittent?

Comment: @Kev: Good question. I log errors and this HTTP 500 error happens 1-3 times a day for a fraction of seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first stop here would be to enable Failed Request Tracing:

> [Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing in IIS 7](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/266/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis-7/)
> [Troubleshoot with Failed Request Tracing](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/772/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing/)

If doesn't produce anything that narrows things down then have a trawl through the System and Application Event logs.

Finally if it's still not obvious what's failing then it's time to dig out some toys from Tess Ferrandez's debugging toolbox:

> [.NET Debugging Demos - Information and setup instructions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/04/net-debugging-demos-information-and-setup-instructions.aspx)
>
> [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 2: Crash](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/02/08/net-debugging-demos-lab-2-crash.aspx)
>
> [.NET Debugging Demos Lab 5: Crash](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2008/03/05/net-debugging-demos-lab-5-crash.aspx)
>
> [.NET Debugging - Crash Scenarios](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/tags/crash+scenarios/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to dig down to determine the specific cause of the 500 error, be it a transient script error, resource error or a problem related to IIS's configuration.
Setup [Failed Request Tracing](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725786%28WS.10%29.aspx), wait for an error and examine the log output.

Answer (score 0):

1.Close your development environment (e.g., Visual Studio .NET). 

2.Open a Command Prompt, and type the following commands: 

3.      `iisreset /stop` 

4.net user ASPNET /delete    [ u can ignore this step if this fails]

5.   `aspnet_regiis -i` 

6.    `iisreset /start` 

7.Close the Command Prompt. 

8.Restart your development environment.

Comment: Why should this supposedly fix the issue?

Comment: Steps 1, 3, 6 and 8 did it for me.