# Spike in "500 - internal server errors" from web services running on IIS7, Windows Server 2008

Tags: iis-7, asmx, internal-server-error

We have a bunch of websites running on a NLB of 3 web servers. One of the sites is a set of web services which is used to power a news application for an iPad.

On Monday the client called up to say they were seeing some errors on the App. I jumped on the server and noticed a lot of 500s in the IIS logs. I then wrote a script to call the webserverice and managed to reproduce the 500 through fiddler but the response was useless.

The web service gets around 200,000 hits a day. Typically we get less than 10 "500 internal server errors per day". On Sunday however these spiked to 2000 (around 1% of all requests) and have been at that level ever since.

We have had no code deploys since mid June. Our server/network infrastructure has not changed in anyway and I can't explain to the client what the issue is.

I have enabled Troubleshooting Failed Requests Using Tracing in IIS 7 as suggested in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704744/http-error-500-internal-server-error-on-high-load-asp-net-application) but the error message is meaningless to me. I have Googled extensively but no dice, trace details below:

```
114. -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
ModuleName ManagedPipelineHandler 
Notification 128 
HttpStatus 500 
HttpReason Internal Server Error 
HttpSubStatus 0 
ErrorCode 0 
ConfigExceptionInfo  
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
ErrorCode The operation completed successfully. (0x0)
```

The web config is here (with irrelevant parts removed)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
                <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
                <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
                <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication" />
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>

</configSections>

<appSettings />
<connectionStrings />

<system.web>
    <webServices>
        <protocols>
            <add name="HttpGet" />
            <add name="HttpPost" />
        </protocols>
    </webServices>
    <compilation debug="false">
        <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
            <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
        <controls>
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
            <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx" />
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5" />
            <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false" />
        </compiler>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>

<!-- 
    The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
    Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
-->
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
        <remove name="ScriptModule" />
        <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated" />
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory" />
        <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" />
        <remove name="ScriptResource" />
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    </handlers>
    <tracing>
        <traceFailedRequests>
            <add path="*.asmx">
                <traceAreas>
                    <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Rewrite,Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module" verbosity="Verbose" />
                </traceAreas>
                <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:00" statusCodes="500" />
            </add>
        </traceFailedRequests>
    </tracing>
</system.webServer>

<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" appliesTo="v2.0.50727">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos, I had a look at the event viewer but there was nothing in there, (System and Application Event logs).

Comment: We ended up fixing this problem by tuning our database. We ran activity monitor and put some work into improving the recent expensive queries, adding indexes where suggested by the Execution Plan. What I don't understand is why this cause 500 internal server error. Is it possible that IIS was getting over run with requests which it couldnt answer in time and so it dropped incoming ones? We only got a handful or timeout exceptions in our inbox in comparison to the number of 500s, which suggests the method on the asmx was not even getting hit.